# Can't read fetch() json object response

Tags: javascript, ajax, ecmascript-6, fetch

I have controller function that returns:

```
return Json(new { model = testVM, html = RenderViewToString(ControllerContext, "_test", testVM) }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

("model" consists of parameters, "html" is a partial view with html and data)

If I use classic jQuery ajax like this, everything is working fine:

```
$.ajax({
url: actionUrl,
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
cache: false,
async: true,
success: function (data) {
    console.log(data); //{model:{id:1, name: "aa", ...},html:"<span>test</span>"}
    console.log(data.model.id); //I can get ID from model
    console.log(data.html); //I can render this into div
}
});
```

..but when i try to switch to ES6 fetch(), I get errors like (using Chrome debugger):

```
error1: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: a.replace is not a function
```

or

```
error2: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

My fetch code:

```
fetch(url, {
method: "POST",
mode: "cors",
headers: new Headers({
    "Content-Type": "json"
}),
})
.then(function(response){ return response.json() })
.then(fucntion(j){ console.log(j) })
.catch()
```

So the question is how do I access "model" and "html" ?

I have read this https://davidwalsh.name/fetch

[image: ajax response]

[image: fetch - network tab]

Comment: `Content-Type` should probably be set to `application/json`. Sounds like your server is returning HTML. Also you should be checking the response flag: `.then(response => response.ok ? response.json : console.error(response))`

Comment: Are you sure that the POST request works properly? error2 looks like you get an HTML error page, which of course can't be parsed to JSON. Try sending the request with Postman and see if it works

Comment: Can you show us some example JSON? AS you're getting an unexpected token error from your JSON.

Comment: I have updated question, see the pictures..
-tryed with application/json, nothing
-post works, if I use response.text() then i can get part of data

Comment: Are you sure that you are making a `CORS` request?

Comment: To be honest, I am using this feature first time..
When I switch to fetch() the controller function is not called at all, I think it has something with async task
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> Test()